# Publishing Waitress IP in docker container

Tags: python, docker, api, flask, waitress

I have a watiress API, I am trying to make it public in a docker contain, However i am receiving the following error:
return self.socket.bind(addr)
fleettracker_1  | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Here is my Docker-compose yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    fleettracker:
        build: ./fleettracker
        ports:
            - "5000:5017"
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - fullstack
    db:
        image: mysql
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
networks:
    fullstack:
        driver: bridge
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "waitress API.py" ]
```

and here is my waitress API main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    waitress.serve(app=app, host="SOme IP", port=Someport)
```

Comment: What are you trying to set `host='...'`?  (In Docker, it should almost always be `host='0.0.0.0'`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, and how I can make it public?